# how to redirect to previous page after registration in magento?

Tags: magento, redirect

I was trying to redirect the customer to the review page that is a customer has to login or register to rate a product , and i was able to redirect the customer to the review page after login but i could not redirect the customers back to the review page after they have registered to the website, I found the code which is redirecting the customer to the Dashboard but i don't know how to redirect to the previous page.

```
  protected function _welcomeCustomer(Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer, $isJustConfirmed = false)
{
    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
        $this->__('Thank you for registering with %s.', Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName())
    );

    $customer->sendNewAccountEmail(
        $isJustConfirmed ? 'confirmed' : 'registered',
        '',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId()
    );

    $successUrl = Mage::getUrl('*/*/index', array('_secure'=>true));


    if ($this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl()) {
        $successUrl = $this->_getSession()->getBeforeAuthUrl(true);
    }
    return $successUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out myself, 
       had to add a session variable on the page which has the link to the registration page

```
         $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
     $session->setBeforeAuthUrl( Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() );
```

And i didn't had to change anything on the "_welcomeCustomer"  function. 
  That should get the customer back to the page from where they clicked the registration link.